# Authorization integration into client-server app (C#, JavaScript)

Tags: c#, javascript, oauth, openid, authorization

what is the fastest way to integrate authorization into to client-server app, written on .Net (without ASP.NET) and JavaScript?

Under authorization I mean something like OpenId/OAuth or something else without coding my own. Mostly I want to support all or some one of Twitter/Facebook/Google;

**Update:**
I need to know User's name and from where he came;)

Any advices?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

yah check http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/08/01/sql-server-tips-from-the-sql-joes-2-pros-development-series-wildcard-basics-recap-day-1-of-35/

here if you want to comment either you have to enter details or login via some option like facebook or twitter or else.

Answer (score 1):

I've used to use advices from here:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Sep/17/Integrating-OpenID-in-an-ASPNET-MVC-Application-using-DotNetOpenAuthA